# According to TLD or attribute directive in tag file, attribute name does not accept any expressions

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, jsp-tags, ognl

I write the following code in JSP.

```
<%
String p_loginPassword = OpeCommon.LOGIN_PASSWORD;
String p_encryptCode = OpeCommon.encriptPassword(OpeCommon.KEY_USER_ID, OpeCommon.KEY_USER_PASSCODE);
%>
<s:url id="printURL" action="actMod" method="printout">
    <s:param name="<%=OpeCommon.LOGIN_PASSWORD %>"><%=OpeCommon.encriptPassword(OpeCommon.KEY_USER_ID, OpeCommon.KEY_USER_PASSCODE)%></s:param>
</s:url>
```

It displays error : According to TLD or attribute directive in tag file, attribute name does not accept any expressions

How should I write for that, pls give me some suggestions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use scriptlets in the struts tags, don't use it at all in JSP, if you can't you may try

```
<s:set var="loginPassword"><%=OpeCommon.LOGIN_PASSWORD %></s:set>
<s:param name="%{#loginPassword}"><%=OpeCommon.encriptPassword(OpeCommon.KEY_USER_ID, OpeCommon.KEY_USER_PASSCODE)%></s:param>
```

Note, that constants could be accessed through the OGNL expression, and that expression is allowed in the struts tags. But, it applies to the OGNL syntax and you should supply FQCN to the static content. Constants don't require enabling static access in the configuration, but calling a static method is required. If you allow static access then everything could be done via OGNL expressions, if not only constants could be accessed like

```
<s:param name="%{@com.package.OpeCommon@LOGIN_PASSWORD}">
```

Comment: I'm glad that helped!